# Code sample could not be shown on the page

Tags: support, bug, markdown, code-block

The code samples could not be showed in the page and the markdown editor is also not working well in my browser.

I'm  using Chromium (Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) Built on Ubuntu, running on LinuxMint 19.1 (64-bit).)

> [image]
>
> [image: test]

Comment: What extensions do you have installed? Try disabling them one by one and check if it works after each one.

Comment: I don't install any extensions yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it was my fault. I installed a font from OS X named [Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monaco_(typeface)), and it will let the

```html
<pre><code> ... </code></pre>
```

structure doesn't works well. Well, the structure apply Monaco as a value to its font-family CSS attribute.

I uninstalled the Monaco font, and it works now. Sorry to disturb.

Comment: You should accept your answer, to let users know the issue has been resolved.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that's a good idea, but they can't within 48 hours of posting the question.

Comment: @Glorfindel Oh, I didn't realize the question was only posted 9 hours ago. And I forget about that time restriction about "self-accepting".

Comment: Font? Typeface?

Comment: @PeterMortenen  I think it is. I checked all the CSS attributes have been applied to the <pre> and <code> tag and I think they're ok, then I disabled the `font-family` attribute and the sample code appeared, so I remove the fonts one by one to check which font I should remove, finally I got it.